# Explain the meaning of ' i ' in the following code

Tags: python

```
import random

for i in range(5):
 
    print(random.randint(1, 10))
```

Is it the number of integers that we want to print? But we didn't specify that it's the number of integers in the code, so how does python understand?

Comment: Which number we want to print?

Comment: you need to understand the range functions https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

Comment: `i` isn't used so it has no meaning at all

Comment: It isn't use. You need to put it because it's the form you've to write a for loop in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(5):
  do this action
```

Is (the Python way of saying

"for each element in **range(5)**
do this action".

`range(5)` can be replaced by any iterable collection.
In this example the variable i is not used. We might write

```
for i in range(5):
  print(i)
```

which would print out all the values from the expression `range(5)`.

Comment: `for i in range` not `for i int range` ... typo but there's not enough characters to justify an edit

Answer (score 1):

The Python *for* construct **requires** a variable name between *for* and *in*. Conventional practice is to use _ (underscore) as the variable in cases where a variable is required but not actually used/relevant. Note that _ is a valid variable name.

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed, `i` in that code will be the number of random integers to be printed. That is because, in python, the [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) constructor will generate a sequence of integers when specified in the way you are showing.

If only one argument is specified, python will assume that you want to begin by the number zero, incrementing by one unit until it reaches the number one unit below the specified argument.